# Calculate EVI From Landsat 8 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, ndvi, landsat-8, evi

I have calculated atmospherically corrected reflectance values for Landsat 8.

From that, I am getting correct values of NDVI in QGIS, but for EVI I am not getting the correct values. For some images it goes beyond 1 and for others it shows black output in QGIS.

I am using the EVI formula derived for MODIS.

Comment: Could you please include the EVI implementation you used in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

```
EVI = 2.5 * (NIR-Red)/(NIR+6*Red-7.5*Blue+1)
```

I have used [this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_vegetation_index) in the raster calculator of QGIS.